# REGEX with line breaks in php

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression in php without reaching my goals ...
Here is my string:

```
$string = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx "segment

to

recovered with line breaks" xxxxx "other segment without line break" xxxx';
```

I would like to retrieve the segment in quotation marks, with line breaks, without retrieving the segment in quotation marks without a line break.

Here is my current REGEX:

```
preg_match('/\"[^\"$]*\"/', $string, $match);
```

Could you get me out of there please?

Comment: First of all, use regex delimiters with PHP regex, then, if you plan to stay within the same line, negate CR and LF at least, e.g. `'~"[^"\r\n]*"~'`

Comment: Thanks for your help, It's a mistake. I try your REGEX but he take every segment in quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead to match a linebreak:

```
$string = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx "segment

to

recovered with line breaks" xxxxx "other segment without line break" xxxx';

preg_match_all('/"(?=[^"]*\R)[^"]*"/', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

The part `(?=[^"]*\R)` makes sure we have a linebreak within the match.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "segment

to

recovered with line breaks"
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's works ! But i have on more problem ... The string is a CSV file. When I retrieved the line, i using the preg_replace function to change linebreak into this character £. Now I want to push the new line into the original file but I don't find the solution ... Can you help me ?

Comment: It's okay, i find my happiness in preg_replace_callback !